# SQL Server / OLEDB DateTimes to NodaTime Instant - Safest Method

Tags: datetime, timezone, oledb, nodatime

I have an issue with converting date times when the original data comes from a SQL query (LINQ in this instance) or over OLEDB (same issue on both).

I am using NodaTime, however the issue is that I appear to need to go via System.DateTime before getting to a Noda Instant, and at this point errors are introduced.

The timezone of the data in the source data is always known, in most cases its UTC.  However for some reason the code is interpreting it as local system time (I guess), as when I call `ToUniversalTime()` it is shifting the time stamp by an hour.

What is the best way of converting a database datetime object to a NodaTime Instant without the risk of any System time intervention?

As I know the Timezone of the source data, I need to convert this to the correct Instant without the system applying an assumed TimeZone behind the scenes.

Example OleDb code:

```
var cmd = String.Format("SELECT [{0}] AS EquipRef, [{1}] AS MeasureTimeStamp, [{2}] AS MeasureValue FROM [{3}]", equipRefColumn, timeStampColumn, columnName, tableName);
var dataTable = new DataTable(tableName);

using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, conn)) {
    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
}

var dataContainer = new DataContainer();
dataContainer.Data.Add(tableName, new List<Row>());

foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) {
    var timeStamp = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(((DateTime)row["MeasureTimeStamp"]).ToUniversalTime());
    dataContainer.Data[tableName].Add(new Row() {ColumnName = columnName,EquipRef = row["EquipRef"].ToString(), TimeStamp = timeStamp, Value = row["MeasureValue"]});
}
```

Example LINQ to SQL code:

```
var db = new RawDataStoreDataContext(new SqlConnection(ConnectionString));

var tables = db.Tables_Get(SourceDataLinkId);
var equipRefs = db.EquipRefs_Get(SourceDataLinkId);

foreach (var table in tables) {
    foreach (var equipRef in equipRefs) {
        var rawData = db.RawData_FetchByTableAndEquip(equipRef.EquipRef, table.TableName, SourceDataLinkId);

        var dataContainer = new DataContainer();
        dataContainer.Data = new Dictionary<string, List<Row>>();

        dataContainer.Data.Add(table.TableName,new List<Row>());
        foreach (var row in rawData) {
            var timeStamp = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(row.TimeStamp.ToUniversalTime());
            dataContainer.Data[table.TableName].Add(new Row() {ColumnName = row.ColumnName,EquipRef = equipRef.EquipRef,TimeStamp = timeStamp,Value = row.Value});
        }
        dataTarget.Stage(dataContainer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ToUniversalTime`, use `DateTime.SpecifyKind` and pass `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

In your OLEDB code:

```
var timeStamp = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)row["MeasureTimeStamp"], DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

In your L2S code:

```
var timeStamp = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.SpecifyKind(row.TimeStamp, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

Comment: Aside - why use oledb?  Why not just the native SQL client?

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  And Oledb is used to fetch data from MS Access files